# Python Geopandas: World map with higher resolution

Tags: python, pandas, maps, gis, geopandas

I am looking for a way to easily plot a world map with a higher resolution compared to the built in resolution of Geopandas. To my knowing the built in dataset for a world map is only in low resolution:

```
import geopandas
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
plt.show()
```

I already read this page but couldn't find an answer: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html#

I am not looking for google maps precision, but I would appreciate a map where if I zoom in, Belgium for example is plotted by a polygon which has a bit more than 14 points (see screenshot). (Let's say 100 to 1000 points.)

(I need the full map of the world as I am plotting data in different countries and would like to zoom in.)

[image: low resolution map]

Comment: geopandas packages the data from https://www.naturalearthdata.com it uses low res for simple reason it's just meant as sample data.  You can download the medium res or high res.  see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/main/geopandas/datasets/naturalearth_creation.py for details of how it selects columns and defines **iso_a3**

Answer (score 2):

That's a limitation of the data that built-in polygons have. Vectors represent the map as it is, regardless of zooming in on the map.

As the number of points that make up a polygon increases, a more precise map requires more capacity.

You will be able to use a variety of sources.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182944/seeking-polygon-shapefile-of-countries-states-and-islands

The sites listed in the answers above will help.
Get and load world borders from OSM or GADM. I haven't checked the size of the data, but the closer the boundaries are to reality, the larger the size of the data and the memory requirements to load the file.